# XCode4 - How to change only directory folder name

Tags: iphone, xcode4, directory

When creating a project in XCode 4 with the name My_Project, the default folder that is created is contains a subfolder with the same name that contains all the headers, plists, etc. I don't want my project to have nested folders with the same name(ex. My_Project -> MyProject).

How do I go about changing the directory name from "My_Project" to something like "My_Project_Source". I've found plenty on renaming the whole project but I just want to change that folders name to something more descriptive.

When trying to solve this I renamed the folder and updated the references. Still the compiler is looking for the info.plist and such in the default directory name "My_Project". There must be something I'm missing in the build setting.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the items in the Target build settings like those shown in the image below:

[image]

For example, if I renamed my folder from `XML Signature Finagler` to `srcFolder`, I'd need to change the `Info.plist File` setting to `srcFolder/XML Signature Finagler-Info.plist`. Likewise, the Prefix Header path would need to be updated as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Also, for the infoPlist I had to change the location to "Relative to Project".